# Auto-update a Windows Service

Tags: windows-services, auto-update

I am about to develop a program which will be installed and run as a Windows Service on the back-end servers (with internet access) of several clients. I do not have physical access to the servers. What I am working on is a scheme for reliably rolling out updates to the program.

I have spend quite a lot of time looking for best practices for Windows Service auto-updates, but have found very little useful information. Most techniques, such as ClickOnce, seem to cater primarily for Windows Forms-based applications.

My current plan is:

- When updates are available, have the running service download, install, and start an update service.
- The update service will download the new version of the main service and install it side-by-side of the current, still active version.
- The update service next stops the old version and then starts the new version of the service.
- The new version disables the update service during startup.

Some important concerns for me are:

- Being able to handle updates both to the main service and the update service
- Being able to handle interruptions such as power failure or a connection failure at any point during the update process

What am wondering is if this a common way to solve this problem and/or if I am missing anything crucial. Is it too complicated, or perhaps far too simplistic? How would you have done it (or, even better, how have you done this successfully)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I was faced with the same problem last year and I wrestled with a lot of the same questions. A few bits of advice:

- Since either service may be updated,
  both services will function as
  updaters of the other. Service A will
  update Service B and vice versa.  For
  this reason, I suggest simply running
  both services at all times.  Unless
  you are worried about really loading
  down your server with
  does-update-exist calls, the
  enable/disable service management
  isn't worth the overhead.
- Like services can't be installed on a
  single machine. In other words, you
  can't install new and old versions of
  the service side-by-side if they have
  the same name.  Unless you want to
  complicate your update process, I
  suggest you uninstall the old version
  and then install the new version. 
  For example, Service A would download
  Service B Installer, uninstall
  Service B, install new version of
  Service B and then run.  Service B
  would do the same for Service A.
- Since each service is managing the
  other, they should not only check for
  available updates but they should
  verify each other's health.  For
  example, Service A would check to see
  if Service B exists and if it is
  running.  If the health check fails,
  a list of steps to resolve the issue
  and get the service running would be
  completed by Service A. Executing the
  health check and recovery operations
  will cover you now matter what issue
  arises with the update, initial
  install or general operations.
- Do ample logging on both the client
  and the server.  You'll want to track
  what actions were taken and when. 
  For example, Service A might when it
  is checking for updates, when it is
  executing the health check and
  associated actions.  On the service
  (assuming you are calling into a web
  service looking for updates) track
  the calls made by each Service. If
  your Services aren't getting updated
  at least you'll have a trail of
  breadcrumbs (or lack of breadcrumbs)
  pointing you to the problem.

There are literally bunches of potential gotchas with a solution of this sort: services not running at startup, UAC getting in the way, not being able to install and uninstall the services with the same user, ensuring user installing the service has ample permissions, connectivity loss, getting the .NET Framework installed on the client machine, handling reboot after install if necessary, etc.

Best of luck. It's a fun problem to solve, but it doesn't go without it's frustration -- especially since, as you said, there isn't a lot of documented information available.

Comment: Thanks for valuable input. How did you handle the potential situation where the update process is interrupted after the old version is uninstalled but before the new one has been installed? Did you keep track of how far in the process you were?

Comment: I don't do incremental installs. The service is either installed and running or it isn't.  Therefore I don't keep track of how far along the process I am.  I *simply* use the health checks to determine if something isn't right and reattempt the installation if necessary.

Comment: @Ben Have you published your experiences somewhere?

Comment: thanks for the reply. Why can't we just stop the service. Override the files where ever its got installed and start the service. We will override all files except configs. We need not to uninstall and install it again i guess???